# Ansible upload file to the immediate root directory

Tags: ansible, scp, provisioning

I'm trying to mimic this neat `scp` command with *Ansible*:

```
scp local_file user@remote_host:
```

Above would upload `local_file` to the `remote_host` `/home/user`.
The **BIG** problem with *Ansible* is that it expects *absolute path* in `dst`, which I cannot provide since I'm uploading to the `router`...

```
---
- hosts: remote_host
  connection: paramiko
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Uploading SSH Pub Key
    copy:
      src="../keys.d/ssh-keyfile.pub" dest="/"
```

This playbook happily fails with an error:

```
fatal: [remote_host] => failed to transfer file to syntax error (line 1 column 5)/source
```

Does anyone know any sensible workaround? Maybe it's possible to initiate local command (on the host where *ansible-playbook* is executed), in my case that would be `scp`, and feed it *Ansible* vars?

Comment: there is a direct way with $HOME variable, however, have you tried just using `dest="~/"`? That works for me

Comment: @MikeD thanks for the hint, but your suggestion does not work and neither does plain `~`. Like I said, I'm uploading to the `router`, NOT *linux box*, so there are no convenience shortcuts like in the most *bash-like shells* where `~` leads to the user's home dir.

Comment: You should clarify the router in the question. Looking at the [router docs](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Use_SSH_to_execute_commands_(DSA_key_login)), you should be do something like this: `ftp -n <<EOF
open 10.20.1.1
user admin admin
put ../keys.d/ssh-keyfile.pub
EOF`. Then you'd have to connect and do `user ssh-keys import file=ssh-keyfile.pub`

Comment: @MikeD My question wasn't about the specific make of the router, for this particular task ansible would fail on the cisco or any other device, where you cannot specify direct path.. I'm perfectly aware, that I have other options, like you mentioned `ftp`, in this case would write a simple bash script and yet push files with `scp` as I want secure channel. However the question is how to do it with ansible, and it's a shame as it seems that ansible is far not perfect in this area.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would issuing a remote command, and capturing the output, prior to moving the file, work?

```
tasks:
 - command: pwd
   register: remote_pwd
 - name: Uploading SSH Pub Key
   copy:
     src="../keys.d/ssh-keyfile.pub" dest="{{ remote_pwd }}"
```

OK, given that the router has a very limited shell, then you could try this (which works to my linux boxes, but I have not got a router to try it on)

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    user: jonathan
    host: 192.168.1.1
    file: /tmp/test
    idfile: /Users/jonathan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  tasks:
- name: scp
  command: "scp -i {{ idfile }} {{ file }} {{ user }}@{{ host}}:"
```

Comment: Nice try Jonathan, thank you, but like I said, it's a **router**, ***not linux box***, ultimately there's no `pwd` command. Router has it's own shell with commands specific to this shell. It's *Mikrotik* router, if you wonder.

Comment: I had a look at Mikrotik routers, and you do have very limited options :-) The above is a local action, that is performed on your ansible host, not the router.

Comment: `command - Executes a command on a remote node` - this is taken from the ansible docs. Hence your example would grab a file on the remote host and then try to upload it to `{{ user }}@{{ host}}:`, given that `scp` is available on the remote host. This is opposite than my exercise and `scp` is not available on the router shell. Though thank you for trying.

Comment: Actually, in this example the 'remote host' is localhost. I used exactly that play to upload /tmp/test to the machine identified by the host: variable. Give it a go.